# Access UI elements in cell from table view functions

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been trying to figure out how to access the objects that are within my cell from any tableView function. Basically, I have this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
```

I need to hide a label in my cell based on an if statement that is in heightForRowAtIndexPath but I can't do cell.notesField.hidden = true as I just get the error 'Use of unresolved identifier cell'.

I tried just using the above code in heightForRowAtIndexPath but this doesn't seem to work and neither does var cell = CustomTransactionTableViewCell().

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should only really be configuring table view cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Whatever determination being made whether to hide `notesField` should be made in that method.

Comment: I've tried setting the boolean in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and then doing `cell.notesField.hidden = the boolean` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, however it doesn't seem to work. How do I update `cellForRowAtIndexPath` once I've changed the variable?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't. Either figure out whether or not to hide `notesField` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, or layout the cell in such a way that displays correctly at different sizes.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread that the first time. Ok, so I'm now figuring out whether or not to hide the label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` however it it's never called. Is there a way to reload `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?